# Use xhr code error on switch/case (javascript)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to display some modal depending on the xhr error code, but I don't know why my switch is failing:

```
error: function (xhr) {
    var codigo_error = parseInt(xhr.status);
    console.log("codigo_error: " + codigo_error);//this shows 404
    switch (codigo_error){
        case 404: body = "Error 404";
        default: body = "Other";
    }
    modal(body);
}
```

I always get the `default` case but in console.log I can see the `404`. i tried with `case '404'` but there's no difference.

And if I put `if(codigo_error == 404) alert(codigo_error);` I can see the alert with `404`

Comment: Did you try with `case '404':` ? and you are forgetting `break` or `return`

Comment: you forgot `return` or `break` statement which is why it seems overwriting to default.

Comment: `case` should have `break` or `return`.

Comment: WOPS, that's right. I forgot `break` thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I always use a break in my switch cases.

```
switch(codigo_error){
    case 404:
        body = "Error 404";
        break;
    default:
        body = "Other";
        break;
}
modal(body);
```

Try that and see if it works.